# Как убрать появление фиксированой шапки сайта при скролле в теме I-craft(wordpress)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, wordpress

Для магазина на Wordpress я использую тему I-craft. Мне нужно убрать всплывающую фиксированную шапку при скролле. [Вот сайт.](http://avto.fof.com.ua/)

Как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте из вашего /js/functions.js убрать этот фрагмент кода:

```
nav_container.waypoint({
    handler: function(direction) {

        if (direction == 'down') {
            nav_container.css({ 'height':nav.outerHeight() });      
            nav.stop().addClass("fixeddiv").css("top",-nav.outerHeight()).animate({"top":top_spacing});
        } else {

            nav_container.css({ 'height':'auto' });
            nav.stop().removeClass("fixeddiv").css("top",nav.outerHeight()).animate({"top":""});
        }

    },
    offset: function() {
        return -nav.outerHeight()-waypoint_offset;
    }
});
```

Comment: я попробовал иначе - заменил позиционирование с fixed на absolute для .fixeddiv . А так же присвоил position: static для .site-header. Вроде бы работает. Но спасибо за Ваш совет.

Comment: @nirolo1 но выполнение кода-то не прекращается. корректнее будет его удалить

Comment: Да, сейчас попробую убрать. Есть некоторые моменты что при резком скролле до верха сайта видно изменение в шапке.

Comment: @nirolo1 уберете код - этих изменений вообще не будет

Comment: убрал, помогло. Спасибо